# Remove/ Reset Class not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remove/ Reset Class not working on my code for an alert .show and fade when a save button is clicked on. Can someone tell me why this code does not remove the class so that the fade works every time I click save as opposed to only once.

Please see below for more information.

The HTML

```
       <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="implicitSave()"
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
       </button>
```

The .js

```
            function implicitSave(){
                console.log("implicitSave");
                var redirect = "";
                saveCampaignAjaxCall(redirect);
            }
```

The alert call

```
          $("#successalert").show();
```

The .show function

```
        $("#successalert").show(function(){
        $(".alert").delay(4600).addClass("in").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $(this).removeClass('in');
        })
```

});

Comment: pls provide Html and javascript code so it give more details about an issue.

Answer (score 0):

`delay()` only works with the fx queue, as in it's only for animations, not setting classes, and `show()` is not async, it doesn't need a callback unless a duration is given.

```
$("#successalert").show();
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").addClass("in").fadeOut(1000, function(){
         $(this).removeClass('in');
    });
}, 4600);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, remove class worked on ajax refresh but did not worked on F5 load, I used jquery link in my partial and it worked.

```html
<link href="~/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

you can also use dot before the class name:

```js
$(this).removeClass('.in');
```

Comment: Looks like not a complete answer.